# Нет CDATA wc_checkout_params на страниице корзины woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Делаю одностраничную корзину woocommerce. При переносе страницы checkout в cart перестало выводится var wc_checkout_params в CDATA. Как в woocommerce добавляются параметры в CDATA?

Comment: Как-то давно делал нечто подобное и наоборот переносил cart в checkout. wc_checkout_params отображалось.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно было в настройках woocommerce сменить страницу checkout на cart